# Display output of PHP on another page

Tags: php, web, counter, hit

I got this simple hit counter off the internet and it's exactly what I needed:

```
<?PHP session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION['views'])){
        $_SESSION['views']=$_SESSION['views']+1;
        }
        else{
        $_SESSION['views']=1;
        }
        echo "Total page views= ".$_SESSION['views'];
?>
```

So I threw it in my `home.html` which needless to say is my homepage. I however want the views to be printed on my `info.html` page, but I want it displaying the hits for `home.html`. Does anyone know if that's possible?

Comment: you know this only counts 1 person?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you need to change your pages to `.php` extensions not `.html` if you need PHP to be compiled by the server.

There are probably a few ways of achieving what you need, however i will first point out a few things about php sessions you should know.

1. Session variables are available from any page on your site, providing a the `session_start();` function is called first.
2. Sessions are essentially temp storage. In a nutshell a cookie containing a unique id is saved to the users computer. The unique id is reference to the session information stored on the server (temporarily).

For full info check out [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.session.php)

Because sessions are temp storage and they are unique to a user, you will not be able to show any users visits to the home page made by other users except themselves. To achieve this you would need to create a solution which has global and perminent storage (i.e. DB or File).

Now I will show you the solution to what you have asked, i just wasnt sure of the context, so thought i would explain the constraints.

Ok, so you should include the code below on **home.php**.

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION['views'])){
        $_SESSION['views']++;
    } else{
        $_SESSION['views']=1;
    }
?>
```

This is exactly the same as what you had except i removed the `echo` function.

Now over on the **info.php** page add the following.

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION['views'])){
        echo $_SESSION['views'];
    }
?>
```

This will then display the amount of times the user has viewed **home.php**.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your home.html

```
<?PHP session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['views'])){
    $_SESSION['views']=$_SESSION['views']+1;
    }
    else{
    $_SESSION['views']=1;
    }
```

?>

and this on your info.html

```
<?PHP session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['views'])){
    echo "Total page views= ".$_SESSION['views'];
} else {
    echo "no page views to show";
}
```

?>

But you realize that this only counts a single persons visits, sessions are per person (devise) not shared. And that person will only see his own count; until the session expires.

And you many need to  home.html to home.php for this to work! or set html files to parse as php